# Will an app continue to work if my provisioning profile expires?

Tags: iphone, xcode, setup-deployment

I have an app that is loaded onto one of my development phones. The provisioning profile that was used for this app will expire in a couple of days. So, after the provisioning profile expires will the app will cease to function? or does the provisioning profile expiration only affect building and installing the app on the device?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Once the profile expires you will be unable to launch the app. You can go to the Provisioning Portal ( http://developer.apple.com/ ) on the apple site and renew the provisioning license - once an updated provisioning license is installed on the phone the app will function again (i.e you won't need to do a rebuild).

Comment: Does this also apply to the Enterprise program?

Comment: I've not yet developed an Enterprise app so couldn't tell you sorry

Comment: Yes, it does apply to the Enterprise program. Here is the link:[enterpise distribution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979-CH1-SW16)

Answer (score 3):

There are reports that if you delete all the expired provisioning profiles from the device, a previously running app installed using one of those expired profiles might still continue to launch on that device, but I haven't had a chance to test this on a recent OS release.

A non-expired profile with an appropriate Developer and app ID on the device (even if not the one used to install the app) may or may not be required.

Comment: I just ran into a related scenario.  I deleted all the provisioning profiles related to an enterprise build. And the app continued to run.  (Forced close the app first for the test).

Comment: This seems to happen because of caching. After restarting the device the app will not launch

Comment: I confirmed this (running iOS 6.1)

Answer (score 1):

The app will cease to function.  It will launch then exit immediately.

Answer (score 0):

As davbryn says you won't be able to launch the app, except you do not need to go to the provisioning portal as XCode should take care of things automatically these days.

Comment: Automatically... I like that word