# Connection of Distribution Certificate and Provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, in-house-distribution

Im using apple enterprise license to build my inHouse iPad application. Currently Distribution certificate created through the portal is valid for 3 years. But Provisioning profile created through the portal only valid for one year. In Apple site it says "When your distribution certificate expires, the app won’t launch. Your distribution certificate is valid for three years from when it was issued, or until your Enterprise Developer Program membership expires, whichever comes first. " (follow the [link](http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad802c))

It did not mention about the provisioning profile expiration. Currently my Distribution certificate expires in 2015 and provisioning profile going to expire in Nov 2013. My problem is what will happen after my provisioning profile expires. Will my app work after provisioning profile expire. Or do I need to update the provisioning profile which valid for another year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will be unable to launch app - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4740428/1263701)
2. Renew you profile - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5763827/1263701)

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is (from talking with an Apple engineer), that you will need to update the provisioning profile, sign the app archive with that profile and publish a new version of the application with that updated profile.  We do lots of enterprise development and this is the one pain in the arse I have to deal with once a year for each of our apps.  Fortunately, I created an internal structure so that our users get notified of new app updates and we also have our own internal "app store" application that manages all the other apps.