# provisioning profile on iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I have an iPad with an app on it and the provisional profile has expired...do I have have to rebuild my app in Xcode ? and re-deploy it to the iPad or do I simply have to update the provisional profile ? I have created two iOS certificates (development and distribution) but how do I transfer these to the iPad ????? My iPad is running iOS 6.0 and I am concerned if I update the OSon the iPad the app will no longer work ???
do I need to install an earlier version of Xcode that is compatible with iOS 6.0 (on the iPad as the target device) ???
thanks

Comment: do you still have the original code for the app?  what macOS version are you running on your desktop Macintosh?  Does it already have Xcode installed?  which version?

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer [to this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740382/will-an-app-continue-to-work-if-my-provisioning-profile-expires), you simply need to renew your Apple Developer account ($99 in the US).  Assuming this is the same Apple Developer account you built the original app with you, you can renew and download a brand new provisioning profile and install it on your phone and the app will continue to run with no issues (and no need to rebuild).

If you do choose to rebuild, make sure you set the "minimum deployment version" in your Xcode project to be iOS 6.0, although I suspect there will be plenty of errors and issues that come up with whatever modern version of Xcode you're using.  iOS 6.0 dates from 2012, which feels like an eon ago.